# Issue with time axis while plotting on the basis of sharex is set to True

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, pycharm

[image]so, I have been trying to plot two signals wrt a time axis that i created. when i plot the values against the  signal_1 and signal_2, by specifically mentioning the time axis t, i.e,
plt.plot(t,signal_1)
i'm getting a fine plot with correct time axis. But when I try to do the same with both signals, with giving command sharex = True, then I'm getting a wrong time axis.
I understand the problem goes away once i disable sharex =True, but why isn't sharex working. that is my question.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

#create time array

t0 = datetime(1970,1,1)
hours = (1/1) * np.arange(7*24)
t = Tide._times(t0,hours)


'''
create fake amplitude, phase and period
'''
amp = [4,6]
phase = [250,140]
period = [4,12]


'''
generate a time array for two signal
'''
signal = [[] for i in range(2)]
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(len(t)):
        e = amp[i] * np.sin((2*np.pi/period[i])*j + (np.pi/180)*(phase[i]))
        signal[i].append(e)


fig, (ax0,ax1) = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=1,sharex=True)
ax0.plot(signal[0])
ax1.plot(t,signal[1])

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is Tide? I suspect the problem is you not passing the X to both plot commands.

Comment: The problem is not passing time to both commands, in the second plot command the abscissae are `[0, 1, 3, …, 7*24-1]`, in the first case they are different, and so your artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To share an axis, both plots need to have comparable axes, within the same range (-ish).

In your example you only pass your X values to your 2nd plot. The first will get a standard integer X value (0...N) for each item in `signal[0]`. Unless your `t` values are also in this range, the two plots will not be drawn over one another.

If they *are* equivalent, you will want to do the following --

```py
ax0.plot(t,signal[0])
ax1.plot(t,signal[1])
```

If not, then you will need to modify one of the axes so they are comparable (the correct way to do this depends on your data).

Comment: Thanks, But as i mentioned earlier, I can set sharex=False, (and hence would manually give the same time axis to both plots) and it works, no wonder. thanks anyways.

Comment: `sharex=False` doesn't give the same time axis to both plots, it just ignores the axes for scaling: both plots will fill the plot area, but there is no relationship between them

Comment: ohh. I made a huge misunderstanding wrt to "sharex", thanks for pointing out.